transient, intermittent "No user exists" errors with SSSD and LDAP
I'm using SSSD and Google LDAP. My users can log (via tailscale SSH, if that matters)
in but after being logged in for a while they get errors like:
No user exists for uid 61270005 (also any command that needs network access fails at this point)
If they log out and log back in things work. Some users have reported that just waiting
without logging out / in also resolves the issue.
Any suggestions as to how to debug or fix?
Here's my sssd.conf:
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
domains = example.org

[domain/example.org]
create_homedir = true
auto_private_groups = true
cache_credentials = true
ldap_tls_cert = /etc/ldap/ldap-client.crt
ldap_tls_key = /etc/ldap/ldap-client.key
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldap.google.com
ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=org
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_user_uuid = entryUUID
ldap_groups_use_matching_rule_in_chain = true
ldap_initgroups_use_matching_rule_in_chain = true

[pam]
offline_credentials_expiration = 1

Here's nsswitch.conf:
passwd: files systemd sss
group: files systemd sss
shadow: files sss
gshadow: files

hosts: files dns
networks: files

protocols: db files
services: db files
ethers: db files
rpc: db files

netgroup: files sss

